# store euro currency format in mysql

Tags: mysql

Have been storing UK currency in mysql using decimal 10,2 format.
Am now needing to store Euro currency format which uses commas as decimal separator.
Mysql says the format is incorrect decimal value.

For example:

```
    UK     100,000.00
    Euro   100.000,00
```

Is the best way to resolve this to reformat any euro currency before adding to DB? (understand this may be a PHP question)
Any tips or tricks welcome TQ

Comment: Are you storing money as DECIMAL or as VARCHAR?

Comment: James - thank you, will follow this post TQ
Alvaro - storing as decimal

Comment: Numbers do not have any format. They get a format when you convert them to string in order to display them. And [rules to type numbers into MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/number-literals.html) are very clear.